# Pandas - Use specific record by condition in computation to update a column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried several approaches for this but could not figure out the best solution for now... I am not very familiar with Pandas yet so feel free to suggest any new solution if needed.

How to get the last record for the previous month and use the value for column "ABC"?

I would like to do:

CurrentRow['ABC'] = LastDayOfPreviousMonth['ABC'] * CurrentRow['XYZ']

I tried using below logic:

```
df['MonthChanged'] = df['Month'] - df['Month'].shift()
df['PreviousMonthABCValue'] = pd.np.where(df['MonthChanged'] > 0, df['ABC'].shift(), 0)
df['PreviousMonthABCValue'] = df['PreviousMonthABCValue'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
df['ABC'] = pd.np.where(df['AsOfMonth'] == 1, df['ABC'], df['PreviousMonthABCValue'] * df['XYZ'])
```

The problem of this approach is PreviousMonthABCValue in my where is not updated (that's obvious because only ABC is getting updated).

So if I have below df:

```
Date         ABC     XYZ 
2021-01-01   440     5
2021-01-02   105     10
...
2021-01-31   100     4
2021-02-01   80      12
2021-02-02   50      40
...
2021-02-28   10      44
2021-03-01   3       20
```

Expected output is:

```
Date         ABC     XYZ    PreviousMonthABCValue
2021-01-01   440     5      0  # <- ABC value did not change because PreviousMonthABCValue is 0
2021-01-02   105     10     0
...
2021-01-31   100     4      0
2021-02-01   1200    12     100  # <- ABC Value changed to be: 100 * 12
2021-02-02   4000    40     100  # <- ABC Value changed to be: 100 * 40
...
2021-02-28   4400    44     100  # <- ABC Value changed to be: 100 * 44
2021-03-01   88000   20     4400  # <- ABC Value changed to be: 4400 * 20
```

Do you have any suggestion ? Is the "where" approach a good one ?

How would you do this ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the need for incremental updates of the dataframe makes the standard Pandas methods not the best choice here. (By *incremental updates* I mean the fact that changes in one part of the frame influence the results in other parts.)

From what I can see this might be a way to do what you want:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)  # Just in case

dfs = []
prev = 0
for _, group in df.groupby(df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')):
    if prev:
        group.ABC = group.XYZ * prev
    group['PreviousMonthABCValue'] = prev
    prev = group.ABC.iloc[-1]
    dfs.append(group)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

I'm assuming that the `Date` column is in ascending order (seems to be the case).

For `df =`

```
        Date  ABC  XYZ
0 2021-01-01  440    5
1 2021-01-02  105   10
2 2021-01-31  100    4
3 2021-02-01   80   12
4 2021-02-02   50   40
5 2021-02-28   10   44
6 2021-03-01    3   20
```

the result is

```
        Date    ABC  XYZ  PreviousMonthABCValue
0 2021-01-01    440    5                      0
1 2021-01-02    105   10                      0
2 2021-01-31    100    4                      0
3 2021-02-01   1200   12                    100
4 2021-02-02   4000   40                    100
5 2021-02-28   4400   44                    100
6 2021-03-01  88000   20                   4400
```

Another way could be

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)  # Just in case

def update(sdf):
    global prev
    if prev:
        sdf.ABC = sdf.XYZ * prev
    sdf['PreviousMonthABCValue'] = prev
    prev = sdf.ABC.iloc[-1]
    return sdf

prev = 0
df = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).apply(update)
```

but I don't like the use of the global varibale `prev` in `update`.